# Obtaining $\mathscr{B}G$ from the topological groupoid $BG$; which notion of "nerve" of a topological groupoid/category should be used?

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, principal-bundles, classifying-spaces, groupoids

For $G$ a group without topology (or a discrete topological group),
let $BG$ denote the groupoid with one object and morphisms given by $G$.

Then, as described at [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping#idea),
the geometric realization of $BG$ produces a classifying space $\mathscr{B}G$ for continuous principal $G$-bundles (for $G$ discrete this means a covering together with an action of $G$ by deck transformations which is free and transitive on fibers).

Here, I assume we compute the geometric realization by first taking the nerve of $BG$ as a category (w.r.t. the standard "cosimplicial category" given by Definition 3.4 [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve#NerveOfACategory)),
then taking the geometric realization of the resulting simplicial set.

---

I was wondering how to upgrade the above procedure for topological groups $G$?

E.g., do we place a topology on $BG$, making it a topological groupoid?

Then, to compute the geometric realization,
do we take the nerve of $BG$ as a topological category? (After choosing some topology on the "cosimplicial category"? Ie lifting the corresponding functor $\Delta \rightarrow \mathrm{Cat}$ to a functor $\Delta \rightarrow \mathrm{TopCat}$?)

Is this the correct procedure?

---

Edit: I realized we need the "cosimplicial category" to have a topology; ie it should be a cosimplicial Top-internal category, hence a functor $\Delta \rightarrow \mathrm{TopCat}$. As described at the page linked above, the cosimplicial category is the fully faithful functor embedding $\Delta$ in $\mathrm{Cat}$ as a full subcategory consisting of non-empty, finite total orders (regarded as objects in Cat), one for each positive integer, and the (non-strict) poset maps between them.

Comment: Not an answer, but section 3 of Segal's "Classifying Spaces and Spectral Sequences" may be of interest to you.
See https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/segalclass.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely look at this